# m3u8-segmenter not compiling

Tags: compilation, ffmpeg, m3u

```
root@ip-**-**-**-**:/home/jeff/m3u8-segmenter# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking signal.h usability... yes
checking signal.h presence... yes
checking for signal.h... yes
checking getopt.h usability... yes
checking getopt.h presence... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for strrchr... yes
checking for strtol... yes
./configure: line 4160: PKG_PROG: command not found
./configure: line 4161: syntax error near unexpected token `FFMPEG,'
./configure: line 4161: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(FFMPEG, libavformat libavcodec libavutil)'
```

All my dependencies are in place, including FFMPEG, PKG_PROG, etc but I'm getting these errors and at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions as shown [here](https://github.com/johnf/m3u8-segmenter/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: Yes. That's where I got it from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully compiled this code on a Mac OSX 10.8 but I did get that error before. What I did was to go to those line numbers and comment out those checks.  I believe what its doing is just conducting some verifications for FFMPEG, avformat,..etc which if you followed the directions should already be done.  I then re-ran the ./configure and make.  The final binary works great.  No issues.  Other than that, restart your steps from scratch but skip the aclocal, automake,..etc. and just run the ./configure.  That worked for me also and the binary code is running fine.  I've worked the segmenter hard with no issues, but again, this is on a Mac OSX 10.8.  Good luck.!